# Install ImageMagick for XAMPP on Mac

Tags: php, terminal, xampp, macports, imagick

I'm using xampp to do some localhost tests of my PHP projects, but just realized that I'm missing the Imagick package. I've searched around and cannot find a set of instructions (dumbed down to my level) to install ImageMagick.

I followed a tutorial involving MacPorts only to find out later that you can install it via PECL within xampp (whatever that means).

```
    cd /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/
    pecl download imagick
```

Running the above resulted in:

```
    invalid package name/package file "imagick"
    download failed
```

I'm a web coder with embarrassingly ZERO server-type skills. Any help is MUCH appreciated. I think I read something about needing the devel version of xampp.  Could that be my problem? And how would I know if that's what I've got?

Mac Verion 10.6.7
Xampp version 1.7.3

Answer (score 6):

What are the results of executing

`$ pecl search imagick`

I just downloaded XAMPP to test this, and had the following results:

```
mlambie@destro:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin$ ./pecl search imagick
Retrieving data...0%
Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=======================================
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
imagick 3.1.0b1 (beta)        Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library.
```

Note that whilst pecl can see the package, attempting to install it with `$ pecl install imagick` failed with the following error:

> ERROR:
>   `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/pear/temp/imagick/configure
>   --with-imagick' failed

This is because I do not have the ImageMagick libraries installed on my machine. I rectified that with:

`$ brew install imagemagick`

(I use homebrew instead of MacPorts to manage this kind of thing).

I was still missing the PHP headers, which I installed using the XAMPP Developer Package. I downloaded and installed this from the same location where I downloaded XAMPP from. Note that the Developer Package is a separate DMG entirely.

Once that was done, I successfully compiled the module with:

`$ pecl install imagick`

Comment: pecl search imagick returned: 

Warning: touch(): Unable to create file /usr/lib/php/.lock because Permission denied in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Registry.php on line 835
could not create lock file: fopen(/usr/lib/php/.lock): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

In the meantime, I'm going to look into the developer package of XAMPP.

Comment: Launch it with sudo to give it the permissions you need to run it.